# Apache Tomcat/8.5.3 Manager App 403 error

Tags: tomcat, amazon-web-services, tomcat8

I have tomcat running on an ubuntu instance on aws and I can successfully get to the `If you're seeing this, you've successfully installed Tomcat. Congratulations!` page but when I click on `Manager App` I immediately get navigated to the `403 Access Denied` page.

I've edited the `tomcat-users.xml` file to have a manager-gui role and even made the user have manager-status, manager-script, as well.

Then I shut down the server using `bin/shutdown.sh`, navigated to the page to check that it was actually shut down then did `bin/startup.sh` to restart it.

But whenever I click on that `Manager App` button it doesn't even bring up the username/password box it just goes straight to the 403 page.

Am I missing something else?

Edit: Here is my entire users xml file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
              version="1.0">

  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
  <role rolename="manager-status"/>
  <user username="admin" password="myPassword" roles="manager-gui,manager-status,manager-script"/>

</tomcat-users>
```

Comment: user.xml seams ok to me. Are you changing the correct one?

Comment: @DiogoSantana I think so, I didn't think there would be another one. Is there a way I can see if there are multiples?

Comment: By the way, have you try Psi-probe instead of Tomcat Manager? https://github.com/psi-probe/psi-probe

Comment: It depends on your ubuntu config... I don't use ubuntu

Comment: @DiogoSantana No I don't but I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 8):

This helped me to get it working.
[Tomcat manager never asking me ID/PASSWORD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37154161/tomcat-manager-never-asking-me-id-password)

You need to add the manager.xml to conf/Catalina/localhost

According to the documentation:

"A default Tomcat installation includes the Manager. To add an instance of the Manager web application Context to a new host install the manager.xml context configuration file in the $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname] folder"

In my case for example, I have this path: /opt/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost

Example of manager.xml

```
<Context privileged="true" antiResourceLocking="false" docBase="${catalina.home}/webapps/manager">
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="^.*$" /></Context>
```

Comment: Assuming you've added the roles and users to the tomcat-users.xml file. You can use this trick to access the manager with a Dockerized tomcat server! In the docker file, start with a tomcat base image like 'FROM tomcat:9.0.14-jre11-slim' and then create the folder echos of the lines above into the manager.xml file. Github Gist https://gist.github.com/craigtmoore/b519399d8ce8ba4ae9e450caee287d70

Answer (score 3):

I believe another way to resolve this is to edit the context.xml file that exists by default in the app:

$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml

Prior to Tomcat 8.5, the Valve here was commented out:

```
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
  <!--
    Remove the comment markers from around the Valve below to limit access to
    the manager application to clients connecting from localhost
  -->
  <!--
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />
  -->
</Context>
```

But it seems to be uncommented by default in 8.5. As noted in the 8.5x migration guide, https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-85.html#Migrating_from_8.0.x_to_8.5.x:

**Migrating from 8.0.x to 8.5.x**

This section lists all the known changes between 8.0.x and 8.5.x which may cause backwards compatibility problems when upgrading.

...

**Web applications**

The Manager and HostManager web applications are configured by default with a RemoteAddrValve that limits access to those applications to connections from localhost.

---

So, bottom line, I think you could adjust the context.xml in the app, or make a new manager.xml file and adjust that context element, as described above.

Comment: This solution works for gaining access to Tomcat Web Application Manager `localhost:8080/manager/html`. In order to also gain access to Tomcat Virtual Host Manager `localhost:8080/host-manager/html`, you also need to edit `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/host-manager/META-INF/context.xml` and add `<role rolename="admin-gui"/>` and `<user username="myuser" password="mypass" roles="admin-gui"/>` to `tomcat-users.xml`. I am using Tomcat 8.5.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a context for the Manager App and allow access from Tomcat 8.5.x

Under your `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/` home create a file manager.xml

manager.xml content, note my source is 172.31.254.37 (my computer), change this to your source :

```
<Context privileged="true" antiResourceLocking="false"
         docBase="${catalina.home}/webapps/manager">
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="172\.31\.254\.37" />
</Context>
```

Make sure your User/Roles are defined in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/tomcat-users.xml`

```
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="manager-gui,manager-status"/>
```

Kind Regards,

Jacques de Jager